# Testing Observable Callback to Change Object State

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a service that does the following:

```
  updateProperties(properties: any) {
    return this.http.put(environment.adminApiURLPrefix+'api/v1/properties', properties);
  }
```

In my component I have two objects, providers and providerProperties. Providers contains a key value pair of API providers and their status, whilst providerProperties is the actual response that is returned back from the API (has to be stored as any subsequent requests need the entire object).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProviderService } from '../../services/provider.service';
import { Status } from 'src/app/models/status.enum';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/services/alert.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-providers',
  templateUrl: './providers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./providers.component.scss']
})
export class ProvidersComponent implements OnInit {

  providers: any;
  providerProperties: any;
  status: Status;

  constructor(private providerService: ProviderService, private alertService: AlertService) {
    this.providers = {
      'API1': false,
      'API2': false,
      'API3': false
    }
    this.status = Status.Loading;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.providerService.getProperties().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.setProviderValues(response);
      this.status = Status.Ready;
    },
    error => {
      this.alertService.error('Error');
      this.status = Status.Error;
    })
  }

  setProviderValues(response: any) {
    this.providerProperties = response;
    Object.keys(this.providers).forEach(key => {
      let providerStatus: string = this.providerProperties[key.toLowerCase() + '.enabled'];
      if(providerStatus == 'true' || providerStatus == 'false') {
        this.providers[key] = providerStatus == 'true' ? true : false;
      } else {
        this.alertService.error('Error.');
        this.status = Status.Error;
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  changeProviderProperty(provider: string, isEnabled: boolean) {
    let providerKey: string = this.providerDisplayNameToPropertyKey(provider);

    let tempProviderProperties = Object.assign({}, this.providerProperties);
    tempProviderProperties[providerKey] = isEnabled ? true : false;

    this.providerService.updateProperties(tempProviderProperties).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.setProviderValues(response);
        this.alertService.success('Successfully '+ (isEnabled ? 'Enabled ' : 'Disabled ') + provider);
      },
      err => {
        if(err['status'] == 0) {
          this.alertService.error('Error');
        } else {
          let errorArray = err['error']['Errors']['Error'];
          for(let errorKey in errorArray) {
            let errorValue = errorArray[errorKey];
            this.alertService.error('Error Updating Properties: ' + errorValue['ReasonCode'] + ' ' + errorValue['Description']);
          }
        }
      }
    )
  }

  providerDisplayNameToPropertyKey(provider: string) {
    return provider.toLowerCase() + '.enabled';
  }
}
```

I have the following test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { ProvidersComponent } from './providers.component';
import { ProviderService } from 'src/app/services/provider.service';
import { of, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { AlertComponent } from '../shared/alert/alert.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/services/alert.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ProvidersComponent', () => {
  let component: ProvidersComponent;
  let providerService: ProviderService;
  let alertService: AlertService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProvidersComponent>;
  let getPropertiesSpy: jasmine.Spy<() => Observable<String>>;
  let changeProviderPropertySpy: jasmine.Spy<(provider: string, isEnabled: boolean) => Promise<void>>;

  let providerProperties:any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
        ProvidersComponent,
        AlertComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        ProviderService,
        AlertService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    providerService = TestBed.get(ProviderService);
    alertService = TestBed.get(AlertService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProvidersComponent);

    providerProperties = {
      'api1.enabled': 'true',
      'api2.enabled': 'true',
      'api3.enabled': 'false',
    };

    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.providers = {
      'API1': false,
      'API2': false,
      'API3': false
    };

    getPropertiesSpy = spyOn(providerService, 'getProperties').and.callFake(() => {
      return of(providerProperties);
    });

    changeProviderPropertySpy = spyOn(component, 'changeProviderProperty');

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should enable provider', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(providerService, 'updateProperties').and.returnValue(of({
      'api1.enabled': 'true',
      'api2.enabled': 'false',
      'api3.enabled': 'false'
    }));

    component.changeProviderProperty('API1', true);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.providers['API1']).toEqual(true);
  }));
});
```

For some reason the state of the objects won't change. I'm fairly sure the observable isn't being subscribed to or I am not waiting for the response.

**Update**
After spying on the provider service and checking to see if it had been called after I call changeProviderProperties, it turns out that it was never called.

**Update 2**
Spied on the providerDisplayNameToPropertyKey method and found that it's not being called for whatever reason.

Comment: You can always check whether you are properly subscribing to it or not by ```tap``` operator or by some console logging inside subscribe method.

Answer (score 0):

The method `component.changeProviderProperty` contains asynchronous code. Because you're aware of that, you're running your test in the `fakeAsync` zone. What you're missing is a call to `tick` that simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the `fakeAsync` zone.

```
it('should enable provider', fakeAsync(() => {
    ...    
    component.changeProviderProperty('API1', true);
    tick();
    ...
}));
```

Comment: Yes I feel this might be the issue, but it still doesn't work. Is my spy correct?

Comment: Update, I spied on the provider Service and it turns out for whatever reason, after the tick(), the updateProperties method isn't being called. Perhaps the spy is incorrect?

Comment: On a first glance the spy for `ProviderService.updateProperties` looks fine. I personally would also mock `AlertService` methods, not knowing what's going on in there.

Comment: It's just a simple service that creates alerts. I'm not sure if I'm missing something when it comes to the observable. Should the service be mocked or is spying on it and then returning the observable good enough to execute the callback?

Comment: Spying on the method and then returning the Observable is actually mocking the method.

Comment: Yea I thought it was. So no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Can you please try to replace `tick()` by `flush()`, this simulates the asynchronous passage of time for all timers in the `fakeAsync` zone, just in case `AlertService` methods also contain asynchronous code.

Comment: it('should enable provider', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(providerService, 'updateProperties').and.returnValue(of({
      'ap1.enabled': 'false',
      'api2.enabled': 'true',
      'api3.enabled': 'false',
    }));

    component.changeProviderProperty('api2', true);

    flush();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.providers).toEqual('hello');
  })); 
Theres my test, with flush, state still doesn't change.

Comment: Just an update, I spied on the method providerDisplayNameToPropertyKey and found out that for whatever reason, it isn't being called.